# java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, macos, jar

So when running the following command:

```
java -jar amazon-echo-bridge-0.2.1.jar –-upnp.config.address=192.168.1.105 --server.port=8081
```

I get this error in OS X:

```
,produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.ShutdownMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2016-01-24 18:20:05.554  INFO 19668 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2016-01-24 18:20:05.660  INFO 19668 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-24 18:20:05.675  INFO 19668 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-01-24 18:20:05.850  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.armzilla.ha.upnp.UpnpListener        : Starting UPNP Discovery Listener
2016-01-24 18:20:05.864 ERROR 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.armzilla.ha.upnp.UpnpListener        : UpnpListener encountered an error. Shutting down

java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:94)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:392)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:242)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:299)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:271)
    at com.armzilla.ha.upnp.UpnpListener.startListening(UpnpListener.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-01-24 18:20:05.950  INFO 19668 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http)
2016-01-24 18:20:05.951  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@26caa08b: startup date [Sun Jan 24 18:19:52 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-24 18:20:05.952  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2016-01-24 18:20:05.952  INFO 19668 --- [           main] com.armzilla.ha.SpringbootEntry          : Started SpringbootEntry in 13.731 seconds (JVM running for 14.566)
2016-01-24 18:20:05.955  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-01-24 18:20:05.957  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.b.a.e.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration : Closing Elasticsearch client
2016-01-24 18:20:05.957  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Primal] stopping ...
2016-01-24 18:20:05.967  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Primal] stopped
2016-01-24 18:20:05.967  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Primal] closing ...
2016-01-24 18:20:05.973  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] org.elasticsearch.node                   : [Primal] closed
2016-01-24 18:20:06.002  INFO 19668 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.armzilla.ha.upnp.UpnpListener        : UPNP Discovery Listener Stopped
```

What is the quickest fix?

Comment: Means something else is already running on the port the UpnpListener wants to use.

Comment: @MonaJalal Keep trying different ports until you find one that's free

Comment: I was mostly wondering if I could fine the first available port after the one I entered using some sort of command or script @ErwinBolwidt

Answer (score 2):

In `iOS` use the following commend:

1. `lsof -i:<port-number>`
2. `kill <PID>`

[image: For more details]